# HttpContext.Current.Trace.IsEnabled inexplicably becomes false after second request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, trace

In my web.config, trace is enabled. On the 1st request, in page trace shows up. Then on the second page, Trace.IsEnabled becomes false.  I don't recall ever seeing this behavior before.  I've search the source code everything and I can't find any references to Trace that might be disabling it.

Ref. web.config

```
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" />
```

Here is my work around for the moment, in global.asax, I added this

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(HttpContext.Current.Trace.IsEnabled) //True on 1st request
    Session["TraceEnabled"] = true;
```

I then added this to an early event in a custom base page.

```
if (Session["TraceEnabled"] != null)
    HttpContext.Current.Trace.IsEnabled = true;
```

Trace then resumes as expected.

Why might trace turn itself off? I'd rather fix the root problem than having a clunky work around.

Comment: set the trace attribute of the @ Page directive to true or remove and check this.

Comment: I verified that the word Trace is absent from all as?x pages. (case insensitive search and visual verification of directive line)  The web.config trace section isn't very handy if we have to set Trace in the page directive as well.

Comment: Are you running locally? Does this behaviour exist on your local, dev and staging server? If local, what version windows are you using? Are you using IIS locally or VS inbuilt server?

Comment: It was local, and I think it was the development server, and the host OS was Win7... gee, it's been a few months and I'm starting to forget the details. Maybe I should delete my question.

Comment: I can reproduce this also.  :-)  It's definitely a bug.  It only happens for me within one module in an application I work on everyday.  It happens for me in IE only!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681438/asp-net-tracing-information-goes-missing-after-viewing-certain-aspx-page

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to make a custom implementation of HttpContext.Current.Trace and then put a breakpoint into a custom property when it's set to true, and see what code calls that?  I am not sure where to begin on this, but this is all I can think of.

Answer (score 4):

Have tried to increase the `requestLimit` attribute on your configuration file?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```